# How to get a UIView object to communicate with a ViewController object

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm working on an iPhone app in StoryBoard. It has a `UIScrollView` in it. Inside of this, it has a `SliderView`, which is a custom subclass that I wrote that derives from `UIView`.

Inside `SliderView` I'm executing this method:

```
// Inside SliderView.m
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // whenever someone touches inside of SliderView, this method fires
}
```

Here's my problem. In my StoryBoard, I would like to disable the bouncy vertical scrolling of the `UIScrollView`.

Normally, that would be easy. Assuming I had connected the `UIScrollView` as an `IBOutlet` in the app's main ViewController, I could paste this into that file:

```
// Inside ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't so easy because I want this disabling to occur only when `touchesBegan` is fired.

So here's where I'm completely stumped: **how can I get the SliderView.m file to communicate with the ViewController.m file?**

Comment: Use delegation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: If SliderView is a subview of your UIScrollView, couldn't you simply add (UIScrollView *)parentScrollView = self.superView; parentScrollView.bounces = NO; ? inside your touchesBegan method of SliderView? Probably better off using delegation or using a weak stored property as shown in krzysztof's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate for this:

**SliderView.h**

```
//  SliderView.h
@protocol SliderViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) isScrollViewToBounce:(BOOL)isBounce;
@end

@interface SliderView : UIView
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id <SliderViewDelegate> sliderViewDelegate;
@end
```

**SliderView.m**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.sliderViewDelegate isScrollViewToBounce:NO];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.sliderViewDelegate isScrollViewToBounce:YES];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "SliderView.h"
@interface ViewController () <SliderViewDelegate>
@end
```

`viewDidLoad()` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.sliderView setSlideViewDelegate:self];
}
```

Create Delegate method in your ViewController:

```
- (void) isScrollViewToBounce:(BOOL)isBounce {
    self.scrollView.bounces = isBounce;
}
```

**Also do not forget to remove delegation**

```
#pragma mark Memory management methods
```

`//---------------------------------------------------------------`

```
- (void)dealloc {
   // Release resources here.
   [self.scrollView setSliderViewDelegate:nil]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm living on steam but this looks legit and I'll implement it as soon as I get caught up on sleep!